# Change element.style with media query

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there a way that I can change the element.style with a media query? I have these boxes on my webpage that are created in html using:

```
<div class="colored-box" style="width:400px;height:193px;border:5px solid #8CDADF;"></div>
```

At different screen size, I need that width to get larger to fit correctly, is there anyway to change that in CSS within a media query.

Comment: You can make a rule that is !important, but as far as css actually changing the DOM to manipulate that elements inline styling, no.

Comment: Another option might be to change that inline style from `width` to `min-width` and let the media queries adjust the width larger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do that. I would recommend not using in-line styling since you can't overrule in-line styling with a media query that adjusts the class (not to mention in-line styling is usually bad practice). Here's how you would do that:

```
<style> 
  .colored-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 193px;
  border: 5px solid #8CDADF;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
  width: 800px;
}
</style>


<html>
  <div class="colored-box"></div>
</html>
```

Alternatively if you just want a quick-fix and to keep the code you have you can use !important like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
  width: 800px!important;
}
```

But this is considered bad practice and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `style` attribute with media querie. You need to use JavaScript for it. What you could do is to change the current class:

```
<div class="colored-box">aaa</div>

<style>
.colored-box {
  width:400px;
  height:193px;
  border:5px solid red;
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .colored-box {
    width:400px;
    height:193px;
    border:5px solid green;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML (I am not sure from your question if you do or not) you can use CSS variables in the `style` attribute and then redefine them with media queries.

Such as:

```css
.colored-box {
  --box-width:400px; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
.colored-box {
  --box-width:800px; 
}

}
```

```html
 <div class="colored-box" style="width:var(--box-width);height:193px;border:5px solid #8CDADF;"></div>
```

Comment: this is assuming you have to use inline styles for some reason. otherwise go with Stephan's answer